# PDO : Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

As a pdo class I use https://github.com/indieteq/PHP-MySQL-PDO-Database-Class this is my insert code. While insert action I get an error ( select functions works with out problems ) I have no ideas how to solve it, thanks for help.

```
$insert = $db->query("INSERT INTO post (user_id,post_name,color,start_date,expire_date,content,title,status,rate,category,created,changed,target) VALUES (:user_id,:post_name,:color,:start_date,:expire_date,:content,:title,:status,:rate,:category,:created,:changed,:target)", array( 
                ':user_id' => $this->user_id,
                ':post_name' => $this->post_name(),
                ':color' => $params['color'],
                ':start_date' => $params['start_date'],
                ':expire_date' => $expDate,
                ':content' => $params['content'],
                ':title' => $params['title'],
                ':status' => $params['status'],
                ':rate' => $params['rate'],
                ':category' => $params['category'],
                ':created' => $cDate,
                ':changed' => $chang,
                ':target'=> 1
            ));

Unhandled Exception. 
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined
You can find the error back in the log.

Time : 18:19:05
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined
Raw SQL : INSERT INTO post (user_id,post_name,color,start_date,expire_date,content,title,status,rate,category,created,changed,target) VALUES (:user_id,:post_name,:color,:start_date,:expire_date,:content,:title,:status,:rate,:category,:created,:changed,:target)
```

This is my vardump form $_POST form pass

```
array(9) {
  ["color"]=>
  string(6) "c22bc2"
  ["start_date"]=>
  string(19) "2014-12-31 18:23:31"
  ["expire_date"]=>
  string(19) "2015-01-08 18:23:33"
  ["content"]=>
  string(70) "
sDOROS)()GJ)*(EH)* VN#MT#:????><?<>?>??)T#\\\'\\

"
  ["title"]=>
  string(23) "Tesssssssssssssssssssss"
  ["status"]=>
  string(7) "publish"
  ["target"]=>
  string(4) "stud"
  ["rate"]=>
  string(1) "5"
  ["category"]=>
  string(5) "w_zal"
}
```

If needed

```
$cDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$chang = 0;
    public function post_name()
    {
        global $db;
        $n      = $db->row("SELECT max(id) as id FROM post");
        $post_name = $this->user . "-" . $n['id'] . "-" . session_id();

        return $post_name;
    }

    private function user_id()
    {
        global $db;
        $userid        = $db->row("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = :name", array(
            "name" => $_SESSION['user_name']
        ));
        $this->user_id = $userid['user_id'];
        return $this->user_id;

    }
```

Whole class : http://pastebin.com/ehPazdMm

Comment: Any error mesages now?

Comment: @Mihai the same still check http://pastebin.com/ehPazdMm

Comment: Could I see the code you have now?

Comment: Its the same as in the pastebin

Comment: I'd like to see the change you made when I asked "What if you put the whole array first in another variable and then use that variable?", it was after you created the pastebin.

Comment: uhm its basically $a = array(... and then after VALUES ... ,$a); still same error

Comment: Alright, I can't help you if you refuse to show me your code. Good luck.

Comment: @CamilStaps fine want see it here it is as written http://pastebin.com/uYs5K7Pp

Comment: Can you do a dump on $params

Comment: Its in the question under This is my vardump form $_POST form pass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This database class internally adds the colons already. In the [readme](https://github.com/indieteq/PHP-MySQL-PDO-Database-Class) examples are given where they show that you have to not put a colon in the keys of the array you're going to bind.

You can see this in line 142 of [the class](https://github.com/indieteq/PHP-MySQL-PDO-Database-Class/blob/master/Db.class.php) as well, the function `->bind()`:

```
public function bind($para, $value)
{   
    $this->parameters[sizeof($this->parameters)] = ":" . $para . "\x7F" . utf8_encode($value);
}
```

Comment: Damn, that's nice just needed remove the : from key didn't noticed this

Comment: @Kavvson glad we managed to solve it; sorry that I got annoyed halfway.